# Two Separate JARs with Maven

Tags: maven, package, pom.xml

I want to use Maven to create two separate jars for my project.

One that will include everything under the `**/client` package and one that will include everything under the `**/server` package.  The client package should also contain the sources.

Question 1:  How can I setup my pom to produce these two separate jars?

Question 2:  Is it possible to create both with a single maven command?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, researching, banging my head against the desk, bleeding, and crying, I have solved this by using Maven's assembly plug-in.

Here is how it goes:

I created two separate assembly descriptors.  Firstly, `${basedir}/src/main/assembly/client.xml` (`src/main/assembly` is apparently the standard place for Maven assembly descriptors)

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

    <id>client</id>

    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/client/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
            <includes>
                <include>**/client/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

then `${basedir}/src/main/assembly/server.xml`

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

    <id>server</id>

    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/server/**</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

and added the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/client.xml</descriptor>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/server.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

run `mvn package`... aaand voila!!!  One command... two JARs!... so easy that I want to cry for all the time I spent trying to find the solution.

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2.2:single (default) @ [my project] ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/client.xml
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/server.xml
[INFO] Building jar: [my project]-1.0-SNAPSHOT-client.jar
[INFO] Building jar: [my project]-1.0-SNAPSHOT-server.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.202s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 19 23:43:52 EET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is the wrong way. As described above separate the client and server into two separate modules ...that's the way to work with Maven.

Comment: Separating the project into two separate modules is NOT an option in my project as I need to pack files that would normally be excluded in a plain run of mvn package.  This is exactly what the assembly plugin is for.  Read about it and learn it before you downvote ...

Comment: Despite the nice comment you gave. What kind of files are not included during a package ?

Comment: Sources can simply be added into a separate jar or into the same jar via the maven-source-plugin and not via the maven-assembly-plugin. What do you mean by CVS files/ SVN files? I hope you don't think about .svn folders / CVS/* ? Furthermore if you create a release via mvn (mvn release...) sources package will be generated automatically except you configured it explicit different.

Comment: If I was using a regular Java project I would use the source plug-in, but I am not, even though the project contains Java.  Although I just briefly read up on the source plug-in, it seems that assebly plug-in is much more powerful.  Exclusion/inclusion options are far more extensive that the source plug-in.  This is useful for projects like mine, where multiple maven modules doesn't make sense.
By CVS & SVN files, I mean CVS and Subversion metadata files.

Answer (score 8):

My advice would be to refactor the projects into a separate *client* and a separate *server* project respectively. By adding a [multi mudule](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html) (scroll down) project that contains both projects, it is possible to build the client and the server in one command.

Comment: This is the way to go.  If you have cross-dependencies between the client and server modules, refactor them into a third 'common' module used by both.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use profiles to achieve this. Please see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

I am not sure if you can package both with a single command easily.